# Efficiently validate that data on a page hasn't been changed by someone else since you loaded?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation, yii

We have a page which contains a lot of user editable data that is populated from various tables in a database. The data is in all different forms, dropdowns, checkboxes, input boxes, text areas, etc...

There have been some conflicts where two users load a record around the same time, one makes changes, and then another makes a set of changes. When they save they are unaware someone else made a change and may have just broken a change they made or overwrote their change.

I am trying to implement a solution to mitigate this problem, such as flashing the user an error when the data was changed by someone else.

I am wondering if there is a best practice way to check for this problem? Some ideas I had are

- Submit both 'current' data present in the field, and the 'original' data. Then check which are changed and compare them in the database to see if the defaults differ from what is currently saved. This would work, but seems to be the least performance friendly.
- Use jquery/javascript to detect when a field has been edited, and if it has changed from `defaultValue` then set a hidden field which will be submitted to indicate it's original value. Then it would do similar to what the previous idea did.
- Set a hidden field with a timestamp of when the user loaded their page. When they submit, use that timestamp and check our history table to see if any data on the page was changed since that timestamp. This seems to be the most efficient idea and likely easiest to implement.

Are there any better options or a best practice way to do this? I feel like I am reinventing the wheel for a common problem.

Comment: Sounds like your reinventing git. You need to incorporate version control into this workflow.

Comment: @al76 There is a history system already.

Comment: Perhaps implementing the 'transaction pattern' might be a way forward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are solving a common problem. But it's common because it needs repeatedly solved so frequently. "Optimistic Record Locking" is your path forward. It looks like yii (which I am not familiar with) has capabilities to incorporate handling this. I found [this link](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-behaviors-optimisticlockbehavior).

Whether the yii infrastructure does this for you, or you have to build it yourself, what you want to do (to support Optimistic Record Locking) is the following:

1. Make and Keep an unchanged copy of your data when you retrieve it to the Client.
2. The Client must submit the changes together with the unchanged copy of the data back to the server.
3. The Server's 'update' routine compares the unchanged
   copy to the current record(s). If something has been changed, then it must
   return an error msg and the 'new' current record.
4. If nothing was changed, then the Server does the update.

The alternative is Pessimistic Record Locking, which you can check out. I avoid it due to other issues it has, but there are scenarios where it is more appropriate.